# Self registering concrete implementations of a derived class to a std::map

Tags: c++, polymorphism, factory

I would like to generate an abstract class that contains information about parameters. Each concrete implementation for a specific parameter should then override a `getName()` and `getDescription()` method.

```cpp
struct ParameterInterface {
  virtual std::string getName() const = 0;
  virtual std::string getDescription() const = 0;
  double getValue() { return _data; }
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ParameterInterface& pInterface)
  {
      os << pInterface._data;
      return os;
  }
protected:
  double _data;
};

struct Parameter1 : public ParameterInterface {
  Parameter1(double data) {
    this->_data = data;
  }
  virtual std::string getName() const override final { return _name; };
  virtual std::string getDescription() const override final {
    return std::string("Description of Parameter1");
  };
private:
  const std::string _name = "Parameter1";
};
```

so far so good. Next I would like to have some form of `Parametermanager` class that allows each concrete implementation of the `ParameterInterface` to register itself to that class. For example, this is what I would roughly want to have:

```cpp
struct ParameterManager {
  static void registerParameter(std::string name, ParameterInterface parameter) {
    _parameters.insert(std::pair<std::string, ParameterInterface>(name, parameter));
  }

  static void printAllParameters() {
    for (const auto &entry : _parameters)
      std::cout << entry.first << ", " << entry.second << std::endl;
  }
private:
  static std::map<std::string, ParameterInterface> _parameters;
};
```

This does not compile as ParameterInterface is abstract, would downcasting through dynamic_cast using a unique pointer work here?

In order to achieve the above, my first idea was to modify the constructor of the `Parameter1` class to be something like

```cpp
struct Parameter1 : public ParameterInterface {
  Parameter1(double data) {
    this->_data = data;
    ParameterManager::registerParameter(_name, *this);
  }
  // ...
};
```

but I am not sure if I can pass the *this pointer around like that ... The goal here is that I would like to generate several parameters (which may grow with my project but potentially much more than 100) but I don't want to have a factory-like instantiation of the type

```cpp
class parameterFactory {
// ...
  void createParameter(std::string parameter) {
    if (parameter == "Parameter1")
      // ...
    else if (parameter == "Parameter1")
      // ...
    // many more else if statements ...
  }
// ...
};
```

which would cause a very long if/else statement and requires the internal structure to be modified each time a new parameter is added (violating the Open/Closed principle). It is entirely possible that what I want can be achieved with a factory design pattern (I am new to this), if so, I would appreciate if someone could point that out to me.

To get an idea of what I would like to achieve functionality wise, consider this `main` function:

```cpp
int main() {
  Parameter1 p1(3.14);
  Parameter1 p2(2.71);
  Parameter1 p3(1.00);
  ParameterManager::printAllParameters();
  return 0;
}
```

Currently this only works with doubles (if the code would compile), ideally it should be templated and work with any type. Any ideas on how to achieve this structure would be welcome!

The full example can be found here: https://godbolt.org/z/an3n9e

Comment: What is supposed to happen in your last code example (which won't compile btw, you've got `p2` twice)? Does `p2` override the mapping for `p1`, since all instances are of type `Parameter1`?

Comment: Also note that you are potentially creating a classic static initialization fiasco: if `ParameterManager::registerParameter` is called before main (e.g. due to a static `Parameters1` instance being constructed), then `ParameterManager::_parameters` might not have been created yet. See e.g. https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order on how to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, it should be Parameter p3 (copy and paste error ...). I am not insisting on static method here, but thought it would make things easier. I'll have a look at the link you have provided, but would be interested in any non static solution as well.

Comment: You need to.use different words for the implementation of an abstract interface and the instance of a class.  Do you mean each instance of each implementation of the interface registers?  Obviously the manager cannot store copies then, because then the copies would have to in turn be registered....  When does it unregister?  During destruction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, yes, if you want to store objects of different derived types into a map, you'll have to use some sort of pointer. An `std::unique_ptr` would do fine here.

Now, I would suggest an `std::unique_ptr`, since they automatically take care of destructing the objects when required. However, that means you can't do registration the way you do in your example. I.e. you can't have an object register itself in its constructor, because then the `ParameterManager` would somehow contain an `std::unique_ptr` to that object, while the object would also e.g. be on the stack. And that means you'll get a double free.

So it's not entirely clear to me how exactly you want to use these classes. In this case, I would probably do something like this:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

class ParameterManager {
  public:
    template <class T, class... Args>
    T & createParameter (Args &&... args) {
      static_assert(std::is_base_of<ParameterInterface, T>::value,
        "T must derive from ParameterInterface");

      // Check if T already exists in map, etc.
      ...

      // Good to go, create & insert a T.
      auto obj = std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      std::string name = obj->getName();
      // Note that we can't do obj->getName() within the emplace call, 
      // since the std::move(obj) might be executed before the getName().
      // In which case you're calling getName() on a nullptr.
      auto result = _parameters.emplace(std::move(name), std::move(obj));

      // If there's a static method that returns the name, then the above becomes:
      auto result = _parameters.emplace(T::staticName(),
        std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));

      assert(result.second == true);
      return *(result.first->second);
    }

  private:
    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<ParameterInterface>> _parameters;
};

// Example use:
ParameterManager manager;
auto & p1 = manager.createParameter<Parameter1>(3.02);
```

Note that there's no `static` anywhere in my example. I.e. the `ParameterManager` class is not a singleton. So you could have multiple `ParameterManager` objects all containing different `Parameter` objects. Of course that means potentially having to pass your `ParameterManager` objects all over the place.

If you do need some sort of global manager, then you'll either have to modify the manager code to only have static functions & members (which will effectively make it a singleton), or instantiate a global static `ParameterManager` object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, much appreciated. I think I will adapt this and steer away from my original design idea, thanks to the potential weaknesses identified by StefanKssmr

Answer (score 2):

[Darhuuk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66024868/8359552) **already gave a nice answer and I would suggest to use his solution, as your design seems not ideal for your problem**. So why providing another answer here? Sometime, it is nice to get the original concept working to explore its weaknesses. Staying as close as possible to your original design, I ended up with the following:

```
// header.h
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

struct ParameterInterface;

struct ParameterManager {

  static void registerParameter(std::string name, const ParameterInterface &parameter);
  static void printAllParameters();

private:
  std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<ParameterInterface>> _parameters;
};


struct ParameterInterface {
    virtual std::string getName() const = 0;
    virtual std::string getDescription() const = 0;
    virtual ParameterInterface* clone() const = 0;
    double getValue() { return _data; }

    friend
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ParameterInterface& pInterface)
    {
        os << pInterface._data;
        return os;
    }
protected:
    double _data; 
};


struct Parameter1 : public ParameterInterface {
    Parameter1(double data) {
        this->_data = data;
        ParameterManager::registerParameter(_name, *this);
    }

    Parameter1* clone() const final {return new Parameter1(*this);}
    std::string getName() const final { return _name; };
    std::string getDescription() const final {
        return std::string("Description of Parameter1");
    };
private:
    const std::string _name = "Parameter1";
};
```

With a corresponding source file:

```
// source.cpp
#include "source.h"

namespace
{
    ParameterManager& getParameterManager() {
        static ParameterManager p;
        return p;
    }
}

void ParameterManager::registerParameter(std::string name, const ParameterInterface &parameter) {
    getParameterManager()._parameters[name].reset(parameter.clone());
}

void ParameterManager::printAllParameters() {
    for (const auto &entry : getParameterManager()._parameters)
      std::cout << entry.first << ", " << *(entry.second) << std::endl;
}
```

The main is exactly as in your example. In your code you tried to create an instance `ParameterInterface` when registering. As you noticed, this cannot compile, leaving possible slicing aside if the base was not abstract. Therefore, you can introduced a clone function that creates a clone of the given object and stores it in the map. Also, to avoid a potential static initialization order fiasco the static functions of `ParameterManager` use `getParameterManager` defined in a separate source file.

Here are a few things you should consider:

- Once a parameter is registered, changes to it are not propagated to the clone stored in the manager. Therefore, you could simply store the value of the parameter and you would save you a lot of trouble.
- I am not sure if the current behavior is desired: Whenever you register a parameter of the same type, it overrides the old entry in the map. In you main only the last parameter would be contained in the map. To avoid this, make the name another input parameter to the constructor.
- you should use only one of the keywords `virtual`, `override`, or `final`
- my code is not complete, you should make `ParameterManager` a proper singleton

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8rMjqK)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the weak points (which will avoid spending more time on a design which will probably not work down the line). Very useful!